# Export/Download 15000 rows in excel file using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql, excel, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How to download excel file fast with million of records? The code is working fine but its take to much time to download excel from azure server/hosting and when request time out then I get an error:

> 500 - The request timed out. The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

**View**

```
<a class="dt-button buttons-collection buttons-page-length" href="@Url.Action("ExportToExcel","ReportsFinance")">Export All Record Excel</a>
```

**Action**

```
public void ExportToExcel()
{
        var comp = company();
        var JGData = db.Transactions.Where(x => x.IsApproved == true && x.CoId == comp && x.Amount != null).ToArray();
        double debit = 0.0;
        double credit = 0.0;

        ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Report");

        ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Date";
        ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "Group";
        ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "GLName";
        ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "Ledger No.";
        ws.Cells["E1"].Value = "Particular";
        ws.Cells["F1"].Value = "Party Ref Code";
        ws.Cells["G1"].Value = "Party Name";
        ws.Cells["H1"].Value = "TR";
        ws.Cells["I1"].Value = "V #No.";
        ws.Cells["J1"].Value = "Exchange Rate";
        ws.Cells["K1"].Value = "Debit";
        ws.Cells["L1"].Value = "Cridit";
        int rowStart = 2;

        foreach (var item in JGData)
        {
            var postings = db.Postings.Where(x => x.TrasactionNumber == item.Number && x.CoId == comp && x.Amount != null).ToArray();

            foreach (var items in postings)
            {
                debit = 0.0;
                credit = 0.0;
                string number = items.LedgerNumber.ToString();
                var ledger = db.Ledgers.Where(x => x.CoId == comp && x.Number == number).FirstOrDefault();
                string accnumber = items.AccountCode.ToString();
                int gl = Convert.ToInt32(ledger.GLAccount);
                string GLName = db.GLAccounts.Where(x => x.Keyid == gl && x.CoId == comp).FirstOrDefault().GLName;
                var accountcode = db.Groups.Where(x => x.Code == accnumber && x.CoId == comp).FirstOrDefault().Name;
                string ledgername = "";
                string refcode = "";
                string partyname = "";

                if (items.RefCode != null)
                {
                    refcode = items.RefCode;
                    ledgername = ledger.AccountName;
                    partyname = db.Parties.Where(x => x.CoId == comp && x.RefCode == items.RefCode).FirstOrDefault().Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    ledgername = ledger.AccountName;
                }

                if (items.IsDebit == true)
                {
                    debit = Convert.ToDouble(items.Amount * item.ExchangeRate);
                }
                else
                {
                    credit = Convert.ToDouble(items.Amount * item.ExchangeRate);
                }
                
                ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy}", item.EntryDate);
                ws.Cells[string.Format("B{0}", rowStart)].Value = accountcode;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("C{0}", rowStart)].Value = GLName;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("D{0}", rowStart)].Value = items.LedgerNumber.ToString() + ":" + ledgername;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("E{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.Narration;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("F{0}", rowStart)].Value = refcode;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("G{0}", rowStart)].Value = partyname;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("H{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.Number;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("I{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.Type + "#" + item.VoucherNo;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("J{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.ExchangeRate;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("K{0}", rowStart)].Value = debit;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("L{0}", rowStart)].Value = credit;
                rowStart++;
            }
        }

        ws.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment: filename=" + "ExcelReport.xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.End();
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET MVC has no `ExcelPackage` class. What are you using? EPPlus? Your code seems to execute one query for every `item` in `JGData`, whatever that is. You could perform a single query instead to retrieve all relevant rows. Right now if `JGData` has 100 items, you execute 100 queries instead of one. You can load the data into a sheet with `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection()` and avoid the loop

Comment: And far, far worse, I see you execute almost one query per column in the loop. You're probably executing 150K queries instead of just 1. No wonder this is so slow

Comment: I use FastExcel(third party library) it is much faster.

Comment: Not with this code. With this loop and queries, it doesn't matter how fast the Excel library is

Comment: `db.Ledgers.Where` executes a query. `db.GLAccounts.Where` executes another one. There are at least 4 queries in the inner loop, so for 15K items, that's 60K queries performed one after the other

Comment: using OfficeOpenXml; @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: Surely you should be using joins (which may be available naturally through your EF classes already, if there are matching relationships in the data) instead of all these extra queries. It's hugely inefficient.

Comment: It doesn't matter when you execute 60K queries instead of one. At the very least, the entities you use should have relations between them, eg `Posting` should have a `Ledger` property so you can load all the data you want with a *single* query instead of loading individual values. Even better, write a SQL query that joins the tables you want and returns the data you need. ORMs aren't great for reporting queries. There are no objects involved in a reporting query. It's far easier to write a `SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ...` that combines the data you want.

Comment: And even better, you can create specific views in the database or even separate reporting tables (if not a separate reporting database/star schema) to provide the report data. All the time your query run it took `SHARE` locks on the rows which prevented other connections from *writing* to the tables. That query essentially froze your accounting application. There's a reason you *shouldn't* be running reports on top of the OLTP database

Comment: For example, you could create a columnstore table to store transactions with Account, Ledger etc prepopulated. Given the way a columnstore table works, you'd get 2-4x compression and 100x better performance for most reporting queries, even for millions of rows

Comment: How can I execute all queries in sp and after that make excel file?

Answer (score 0):

(This would be a mess as a comment)
I don't expect it to be fast even with Epplus that you are using.

You are first getting a series of Numbers in JGData array (and not clear if those are unique, likely not), then looping and getting data matching to that transactionNumber in the loop, again into another array, and then setting cells one by one.

It could be faster at least with some code revision, get only the distinct numbers in JGData, and do a single query containing those transaction numbers, BUT do not get data into an array, instead let it to be streamed to Epplus package and sheet be filled by LoadFromCollection. All those formatting, done per cell, might be done per column instead. That would at least make it much faster (but anyway with million rows I would never expect Excel to be fast even with Epplus (and actually Epplus is not the fastest way to do that, but it is good to do that on a server without Excel automation).

That being said, your code would look like (I didn't bother to remove some unused parts):

```
public void ExportToExcel()
{
    var comp = company();
    var JGData = db.Transactions.Where(x => x.IsApproved && x.CoId == comp && x.Amount != null).Select(x => x.Number).Distinct().ToArray();
    var postings = db.Postings.Where(x => x.CoId == comp && JGData.Contains( x.TrasactionNumber ) && x.Amount != null);
    
    double debit = 0.0;
    double credit = 0.0;
    ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Report");

    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(postings, true, TableStyles.Medium9);

    
    ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Date";
    ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "Group";
    ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "GLName";
    ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "Ledger No.";
    ws.Cells["E1"].Value = "Particular";
    ws.Cells["F1"].Value = "Party Ref Code";
    ws.Cells["G1"].Value = "Party Name";
    ws.Cells["H1"].Value = "TR";
    ws.Cells["I1"].Value = "V #No.";
    ws.Cells["J1"].Value = "Exchange Rate";
    ws.Cells["K1"].Value = "Debit";
    ws.Cells["L1"].Value = "Cridit";

    var cellEnd = postings.Count() + 1;
    ws.Cells[2,1, cellEnd, 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd MMMM dd, yyyy";
    // ... other columns that need special formatting
    ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();


    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment: filename=" + "ExcelReport.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.End();
}
```

PS: I assumed Numbers count in JGData is not too much to prevent this style of query.
EDIT: I reread the question title and the number of rows was 15K not 1 million as I thought reading the question. Also I didn't really take time to correctly select the needed columns in needed order in the query. You can do that easily with your Linq query or even use a raw query.
Once you do that, 15 K should be subsecond or a few seconds at worst.

Comment: How can I execute all queries in sp and after that make excel file?

Comment: @JagdishKumar, simply write your SP and call from frontend. You can also write and call a raw SQL from Linq to EF (or if specifically using MS SQL, Linq To SQL which IMHO is a little more flexible and faster).